# Use the squeeze theorem to find limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\ 1+|\sin n|}{2n}$.
I tried this:
\begin{align*}
&-1\le \sin n \le 1,\\
&0\le |\sin n |\le 1,\\
&1\le 1+|\sin n|\le 2,\\
&\frac1{2n}\le \frac{1+|\sin n|}{2n} \le \frac2{2n}.
\end{align*}
Is the way I'm using squeeze theorem correct?

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you've written. So, what is the limit, and why?

Comment: So far so good. It would be cleaner to use $0\le \frac{1+|\sin n|}{2n}\le \frac{2}{2n}$. Then you need to come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $\lim \frac{C}{n} = 0 $ for constant $C$, then the limit of your sequence must go to zero by the squeeze theorem.